# Loading texture from constructor doesn't work but does from function call

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to load a SDL texture through my class's constructor. All I'm doing is calling a function from the constructor to load the texture. As mentioned in the title, this does not seem to work. However, if I call the function directly then it loads fine and I can see it on the screen. I'm fairly new to C++ so please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

**Game.h**

```
#include "Player.h"

class Game {
  private:
   Player player;

  public:
   Game();
   ~Game();

   void update();
   void draw();
}
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game() {
  this->player = Player("somefile.png", 0, 0, 10, 10);  // Doesn't draw
  this->player.load("somefile.png", 0, 0, 10, 10) // Will draw
}

void Game::update() { /* ... */ }

void Game::draw() { /* ... */ }
```

**Player.h**

```
class Player {
  private:
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect source, destination;

  public:
    Player();
    Player(const std::string& filepath, const int x, const int y, const int w, const int h);
    ~Player();

    void load(const std::string& filepath, const int x, const int y, const int w, const int h);

    void update();
    void draw();
  }
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player() {}

Player::Player(const std::string& filepath, const int x, const int y, const int w, const int h) {
  this->load(filepath, x, y, w, h);
}

void Player::load(const std::string& filepath, const int x, const int y, const int w, const int h) {
  this->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, IMG_Load(filepath.c_str());

  if (this->texture != nullptr) {
    this->source = { x, y, w, h};
    this->destination = { 0, 0, w, h};
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Could not load image." << std::endl;
  }
}

void Player::update() { /* ... */ }

void Player::draw() { /* ... */ }
```

In `Game.cpp`, if I use the line with the constructor then nothing draws in the window. If I use the line that has `load()`, then it works fine. I never get the `Could not load image.` error in either cases.

Comment: is the constructor running before you call SDL_INit maybe?

Comment: I call `SDL_Init` before I do any setup for the player, so that shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you implemented `~Player()` to deallocate your texture.

Anyway, it is rather bad style to copy objects which contain free able resources like here:

```
this->player = Player("somefile.png", 0, 0, 10, 10);
```

What here happens is:

- A new temporary `Player` object is constructed with given parameters.
  Here the constructor calls `Player::load(...)`
- The object is binary copied (field by field) into `this->player` *(notice that the texture pointer value is copied, no new texture is created)*
- The destructor `~Player()` is called on the temporary (presumably deallocating the texture)

**To fix this you have a few options:**

You could use generally just the `Player::load(...)` function for the image loading. And never do a create-copy assignment as above.

Or using the right constructor when you actually construct it:

```
class Game {
  Player player("somefile.png", 0, 0, 10, 10);
  ...
}
```

Or if you need arguments using the initializer list:

```
Game::Game(const std::string& filepath) : player(filepath, 0, 0, 10, 10) {

}
```

Here in both snippets is no temporary object involved which would cause an unwanted destructor call.

Alternatively if you have at least C++11 support, using [move semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move). But like *Quentin* pointed out, you have to implement the move constructor yourself. It might be easier to just disable the copy-constructor.

The difference with *move semantics* is that the temporary object and `this->player` would be swapped so the destructor is called on the old swapped out content.

BTW since C++11 you could also disable the copy semantics on a class which should not be copyable: *(Quentin noted that in C++03 you might also just declare the copy-constructor private)*

```
class Player {
  Player(const Player&) = delete;
  Player& operator=(const Player&) = delete;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I was destroying the texture in `~Player()`. I should have mentioned that, sorry. Thank you for the detailed response, it was really helpful!

Comment: `std::move` is superfluous here, since we're talking about a temporary. You do have to implement the move constructor yourself though. In C++03, declaring the copy-constructor private and not defining it is a good enough emulation of a non-copyable type.

Comment: @Quentin good point, it's sometime since I worked with move semantics in C++. I updated my answer.